What is the official C++ standard?
I thought the official C++ standard was 2023, but according to https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard it still points to 2020. Is this just an oversight of that document? It seems to be an authoritative site.

Current officially ratified standard is officially ISO/IEC:14882:2024.  C++23 is an informal label (not withstanding the fact that the latest draft, approval to ratify, and publication all occurred in 2024).

Official standards are not posted online.  You can find drafts that are not the officially ratified versions.  To get the actual standard you have to pay for it at the standards organization; that's how they get their funding.

Thanks, was just looking for the the current "nominal" version year and was surprised to see 2020 still listed on a reputable site.

Also note : C++11, C++17, C++20, C++23 are all official C++ standards.  In practice you have to select one. E.g. larger companies usually lag behind. Both due to some inherent slowness to change and to avoid potential bugs in early implementations of the standard (valid 20 years ago less so now I think)

@PepijnKramer I think the new standards technically supercede the old ones, you can see that C++20 is officially withdrawn: https://www.iso.org/standard/79358.html But yes, compilers support targeting older standards.

@Moop I usually refer to that as the "latest (released) standard".  E.g right now that would be C++23 .  But yes I can see most people would call that "the standard"

The "official" standard is completely irrelevant at a practical level. No one targets the "official" standard, they target C++11/14/17/20/23 for one reason or another, mostly because upgrading entails a non-trivial amount of engineering effort. People will also start using (parts of) upcoming standards if compilers support it, despite the standard not being ratified yet.

At the time of this writing, C++23 is the current standard, and the isocpp.org website is out of date. C++23 was published October 2024 and is available from iso.org at https://www.iso.org/standard/83626.html
